# How to properly register account using rest api

Tags: magento2, cart, price, addtocart

i have a problem creating a customer account and add item to cart

The API i am using to **create account** :

```
/V1/customers

{
"customer": {
    "firstname": "fname",
    "lastname": "lname",
    "email": "email@gmail.com"
},
    "password": "12345678"
}
```

And then **create cart** using following API without body :

```
/V1/carts/mine
```

**The problem is :**

1. When i add item to the cart via API the price is always 0 or null, but
2. If i create the account from the web, and add item via API the cart has its price

I checked via this API : `/carts/mine/totals`

**Account created from web returns following result:**

```
    {
  "grand_total": 0,
  "base_grand_total": 0,
  "subtotal": 0,
  "base_subtotal": 0,
  "discount_amount": 0,
  "base_discount_amount": 0,
  "subtotal_with_discount": 0,
  "base_subtotal_with_discount": 0,
  "shipping_amount": 0,
  "base_shipping_amount": 0,
  "tax_amount": 0,
  "base_tax_amount": 0,
  "weee_tax_applied_amount": null,
  "subtotal_incl_tax": 0,
  "base_currency_code": "USD",
  "quote_currency_code": "USD",
  "items_qty": 0,
  "items": [],
  "total_segments": [
    {
      "code": "subtotal",
      "title": "Subtotal",
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "code": "shipping",
      "title": "Shipping & Handling",
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "code": "grand_total",
      "title": "Grand Total",
      "value": 0,
      "area": "footer"
    }
  ]
}
```

**while account created from API return different result :**

```
 {
  "grand_total": 0,
  "weee_tax_applied_amount": null,
  "base_currency_code": "USD",
  "quote_currency_code": "USD",
  "items_qty": 0,
  "items": [],
  "total_segments": [
    {
      "code": "subtotal",
      "title": "Subtotal",
      "value": null
    },
    {
      "code": "shipping",
      "title": "Shipping & Handling",
      "value": null
    },
    {
      "code": "grand_total",
      "title": "Grand Total",
      "value": null,
      "area": "footer"
    }
  ]
}
```